# bash: bad interpreter: permission denied

Tags: linux

When I try to execute my script I encounter an error:

```
bash: /home/thai/first3.sh: /home/thai: bad interpreter: permission denied
```

Here's my script:

```
    #!/home/thai

    for file in *
    do
    if grep -l 'main()' $file
    then 
    more $file 
    fi
    done
    exit 0
```

I believe something's wrong with my script but I couldn't figure it out, can someone help me please. I'm running Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring an incorrect [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). The first line of your file should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Instead of your `HOME` directory. In addition, your script could be simplified too. Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(grep -l 'main()' *); do
    more $file 
done
```